# How to reset a navigation multiple navigation stacks on user auth change?

Tags: react-navigation

I have been using react-navigation for a couple of months now for my react native/Expo app and it's been quite helpful. However, I have troubles understanding the reset mechanism and would be very grateful if someone would explain it to me since the documentation provides almost no details about it.

I have nested stack navigators, a bottom tab bar navigator and a drawer in which I have a logout button that can be called from any screen of the app. Let's say this is my navigation

```
HOME
DASHBOARD
POST
  PostList (initial route of the stack)
  PostCreate
  PostEdit
PAYMENT
```

When I go to post list, then post create and then Dashboard. After logout I'm redirected to HOME, I log in with another account, and if I try to go to the initial route of post, I'm redirected to PostCreate instead of PostList.

I tried to dispatch a reset action when my logout button is pressed but this doesn't seem to be a reliable solution because for some reason, I can't redirect to HOME from my Drawer when the DASHBOARD Screen is active.

```
const goToHomeAction = StackActions.reset({
            index: 1,
            actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: HOME_ROUTE })],
        });
        this.props.navigation.dispatch(goToHomeAction);
```

It throws an error "there is no route defined for key HomeRoute, must be one of 'Dashboard'".

Is there a way to just simply clear all navigation state, just go back to the initial screen of the app and clear all the stack navigators so the user would go to their respective initial screens ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried many differents ways including popToTop which partially solved my issue. But I realize the structure of my project's navigation was really messy so I ended up restructuring it completly.

https://www.reactnativeschool.com/complex-navigation-example-with-react-navigation

This tutorial helped a lot, I highly recommend it to anyone having trouble understanding react navigation.

I divided my whole app between two stack navigators, AuthStack (where I put all the Authentification logic) and AppStack (which contains all the screen that requires the user to be logged in) with Dashboard as an initial route.

This is the method I use to clear my navigation whenever a user log in :

```
 public goToDashboardAndClearNavigation = () => {
   const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
      index: 0,
      actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: DASHBOARD })],
      key: DASHBOARD
    })
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction)
  }
```

And I added this lifecycle method to redirect the user to the Login Screen after logging out in the Dashboard screen component:

```
  public componentDidUpdate = (prevProps: any) => {
    if (prevProps.user !== null && this.props.user === null) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate(LOGIN)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `popToTop`. 
The popToTop action takes you back to the first screen in the stack, dismissing all the others. So this will take you to the HOME_ROUTE

```
this.props.navigation.dispatch(StackActions.popToTop());
```

Hope this helps!!